# How to get post revisions in my custom rest API?

Tags: functions, rest-api, revisions

I want to fetch all post revisions for my posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From just looking at your snippet you're not actually setting `$post_revisions` to any value before assigning it to your `$post_data` array

Comment: @Ricky post revisions aren't stored in the post object like that but there's a handy function provided by WordPress to get them. You can have a look at that here [wp_post_revisions()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_revisions/)

Comment: Actually I wanted to make $post_revisions = wp_get_post_revisions($post_id = 31, $args = null); dynamic, so that there will be no need of changing id's again and again

Comment: You can use the post ID of the current post in your loop to ensure that it's getting the revisions for the right post each time